# If true use css, else don't

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm creating a calendar with appointments.
I pull the appointments from a database, from two tables.

Here is my css:

```
      <style type="text/css">
           .rsMonthView .rsAptContent 
            {  
              background: #D0ECBB; 
            }

            .rsDayView .rsAptContent 
            {  
              background: #D0ECBB;  
            }

            .rsWeekView .rsAptContent 
            {  
              background: #D0ECBB;  
            }

            .rsTimelineView .rsAptContent 
            {  
              background: #D0ECBB; 
            }
    </style>
```

However, I don't want it to be applied to every cell of the calendar, but only those appointments which come from the first table. The code for my css is in the .aspx file. How to make an if command in the .aspx file which will check from which table is the appointment?

Comment: Why not add a class in the code for each of those cells?

Comment: I have classes, but they the in the .cs file, not in the .aspx.

Comment: Why not just give the first table an `id`, and then use an `#id` rule in your CSS selectors?

Comment: Please post relevant code behind - how you read the data from database? Are the table linked? We need more details. When you answer comment, please use `@` to notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is really vague, but here goes: if your tables are sibling elements you can target them in your css linke so: table + table .rsMonthView .rsAptContent {background: #D0ECBB}

but sibling selector has poor support in most versions of IE